# AJAX Output result to a dropdown select (c#,html)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX to send a value from one html select drop down list from an ASPX page to the code behind page (C#) and then manipulate it and send it back to be used in order to fill out another select drop down list.

I know the AJAX is sending the right value from the first drop down because I tested and outputted. However, I think I am going wrong in my C# code where I am trying to write it into a drop down list form with the options. I just want the C# to fill the drop down list, and it will be sent back and written to the actual drop down in the ASPX page via Jquery AJAX.

Here is the code:

ASPX: These are my selects.

```
<select id="park">
  <option value="0">ALL</option>
  <option value="C">Central</option>
  <option value="W">West</option>
  <option value="E">East</option>
</select>

<select id="building"></select>
```

Above this I have my ajax function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#park').change(function () {
            var parkValue = $('#park').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Preference.aspx/ShowBuildingSelect",
                data: JSON.stringify({ parkValue: parkValue }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#building').html(result.d);
                    //alert(result.d);
                }
            }
            )});
        });


    </script>
```

C#: Here is my function which gets the value passed i.e. parkValue, and manipulates it using it in an SQL query to get the values I need for another drop down list.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string ShowBuildingSelect(string parkValue)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ParkConnectionString"].ToString());
        string result = "<option value='0'> - ALL - </option>";
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "Select Building_Code, Building_Name From [newBuilding] Where Park_ID='" + parkValue + "'";
        SqlCommand buildings = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader buildingsNew = buildings.ExecuteReader();

        while (buildingsNew.Read())//Add the results to the dropdownlist
        {
            result += "<option value ='" + buildingsNew.GetString(0) + "'>" + buildingsNew.GetString(1) + " (" + buildingsNew.GetString(0) + ")</option>";
        }
        conn.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I assume its the C#. If not then my success function in my AJAX might be wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Whats the error? You dont receive parkValue in the c# code? Did u check in debug mode what value it contains?

Comment: There is no error, I just can't get it to output it to the select #building. It definitely gets the right value, i.e. C for central, E for east and W for west since I've tested it. But I just don't know how to write it to the select.